# What is the difference between using an open or a closed configuration for a microfluidic chip?

Tags: biotechnology

I am doing a college BioMed project on Lungs-on-a-chip to make disease models and I have seen some authors use open configurations, while others use closed configurations. What advantages and disadvantages do they offer on the making of this device?